# Completely Remove Facebook Application from page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am successfully removing a tab from a facebook page with the following PHP:

```
$facebook->api('/'.$p_PageId.'/tabs/app_'.$p_AppId, 
               'DELETE', 
                array("access_token" => $p_PageAccessToken));
```

However the application still sits in the page admin's 'added apps' section and can have it's settings changed so that it is added again to the page. This is messy and I don't want a user to think they have removed an application only to find it sitting at the bottom of their add apps list.

Does anyone know how to fully remove/uninstall the application once it has been removed as a page tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it not just be  ' /pageid/tabs/app_id' not app_appid? Also check the is_permanent field as these can't be removed as detailed here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Although the docs do say that it only 'deletes an installed profile tab' not that it removes an application entirely which is why this could be causing ambiguity, as like you I would expect to be able to remove an application entirely. It looks like it might be the case that a user has to explicitly click to say they want to remove an app as opposed to uninstalling the tab. This might be a security measure to stop people removing each others page applications as this could potentially lead to data in those apps being deleted.

Comment: Hi TommyBs,

Thanks for your ideas. When I print out the returned array 'is_permanent' isn't one of the items in the array. All other items that should be there are, including the malfunctioning 'position' item. So I think the 'is_permanent' item might no be the issue here.

I can't seem to find anyone really talking about this so I can only presume that it obviously can't be done. But I'd love to get other people's thoughts on this.

Comment: No worries, but as I say, I think it's just about removing the tab as removing applications could potentially be disastrous. Much in the same way as I don't think you can add/delete a friend via the api. It would just be open to too much abuse

Comment: Saying that, I've just seen this post http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12000078/deleting-an-app-from-a-user-account what happens if you just issue a DELETE request to /page_id with your app access token?

Comment: Hi TommyBs,

No luck. I get unsupported delete request errors. I tried a few different options in case a slightly different path would work, but no joy. The example you linked to is for the user accounts, not the page accounts. You'd like to think they can both have he app deleted in the same way, but I've had no luck. Really frustrating...

Thanks for your ideas though.